# Slow log package

Tags: performance, http, go, logging

Why does Go `log` package slow my http APIs so bad? Is it that slow?

Here is my router example using [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) **without** logging:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

func main() {
    handler := httprouter.New()
    handler.GET("/hello", f)
    http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", 8080), handler)
}

func f(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    fmt.Fprint(w, "world")
}
```

Using [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) to benchmark that endpoint I got this:

```sh
$ wrk -t1 -d1s -c100 http://localhost:8080/hello
Running 1s test @ http://localhost:8080/hello
  1 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     1.15ms  197.55us   2.84ms   80.02%
    Req/Sec    84.58k     6.15k   99.01k    80.00%
  83904 requests in 1.01s, 9.68MB read
Requests/sec:  83380.37
Transfer/sec:      9.62MB
```

When I added middleware for logging:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

func main() {
    handler := httprouter.New()
    handler.GET("/hello", logger(f))
    fmt.Println("httprouter")
    http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", 8080), handler)
}

func logger(next httprouter.Handle) httprouter.Handle {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        start := time.Now()
        next(w, r, ps)
        elapsed := time.Since(start)
        log.Printf("%s | %s | %s | %d\n", time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339), r.Method, r.URL.Path, elapsed)
    }
}

func f(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    fmt.Fprint(w, "world")
}
```

It got slowed down to the factor of 4x:

```
$ wrk -t1 -d1s -c100 http://localhost:8080/hello
Running 1s test @ http://localhost:8080/hello
  1 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     5.25ms    4.34ms  26.47ms   60.23%
    Req/Sec    20.51k     2.19k   24.28k    70.00%
  20449 requests in 1.01s, 2.36MB read
Requests/sec:  20330.66
Transfer/sec:      2.35MB
```

I tested it locally on:

```
MacBook Pro 13inches
2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5
Memory 16GB

I use default Go max proc without modifying anything after installed.
```

Is `log` package that slow? Any suggestion how to improve this?

Comment: @velkor is right. Use a buffered writer. Also, the middleware that you wrote is doing a bunch of extra stuff as well i.e., logging, `time.Now`, `time.Since`, etc which attributes to performance degradation as well. And I think you should log `elapsed` instead `time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)` to get the time taken (duration) to write the response.

Comment: @shmsr I dont think calling time.Now() and time.Since will degrade performance that much. It's logging directly to os.Stderr obviously.

Comment: you can use buffered writer as already mentioned you can even try logger run async so actual log writing is handled by its own goroutine

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava logging inside goroutine still decrease performance, 2000 rec/sec slower than without logging. I will try the buffered logging first.

Comment: https://golang.org/src/log/log.go#L158 Every log output is synchronized with a mutex.  So if you have that same mutex everywhere, you have to acquire it every time you log.  Imagine what that does for your concurrency

Comment: @WhitePanther I mean use a single go routine to log that loops over a buffered channel so the log function will basically push the logs to channel and will not create a bottleneck to API response time; This imo should work

Comment: @DanielFarrell Exactly  that is why i suggested create a logger that loops over buffered channel and logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer summarizes the commentary on the question.

- used buffered io
- write from a goroutine to reduce blocking from other the logging goroutines.

Here's the code:

```
type writer chan []byte

func (w writer) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    w <- append(([]byte)(nil), p...)
    return len(p), nil
}

func writePump(w writer) {
    bw := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stderr)
    for p := range w {
        bw.Write(p)

        // Slurp up buffered messages in flush. This ensures
        // timely output.
        n := len(w)
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            bw.Write(<-w)
        }
        bw.Flush()
    }
}
```

Set it up as follows:

```
w := make(writer, 16) // adjust capacity to meet your needs
go writePump(w)
log.SetOutput(w)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why do we need that "Slurp..." extra?